# How to store a bitmap to be used for multiple activities in Android App

Tags: java, android, bitmap

I'm letting my app user's sign in to their Google+ account. When they do, I want to display their profile picture in the corner of every activity to show they are logged in. What are some good (and not so good) ways to do this? I thought about converting the bitmap to base62 and storing as a string but I've seen people say that method is not recommended. Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: Why not just store it as a file in local data directory on the device and then load it into ImageView or whatever using file URI?

Comment: Ah ok so just save it to the SD card and store the filepath in SharedPreferences? Something like that?

Comment: Pretty much, just not in SD card - in `/data/data/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would store the file in internal storage and use it from there as many times as you need:

```
Bitmap bmp = ...; // get your bitmap from Google

String filename = "image.png"
FileOutputStream outputStream;

outputStream = openFileOutput(filename, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
bmp.compress(CompressFormat.PNG, 75, outputStream);
outputStream.close();
```

Then later you can load your bitmap from the file:

```
InputStream is = activity.openFileInput("image.png");
Bitmap b = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is);
```

This way the bitmap will even be saved between invocations of your app.

Answer (score 3):

This quite simple you can convert bitmap into base 64 key and use this in each activity 
or 
you can use Action bar which will be similar for all activity

Comment: Action bar better way but it is only for higher virsion

Comment: Be careful with storing base64 in shared prefs - I have had problems storing long strings in shared prefs.

Answer (score 0):

I would highly recommend using a [`LruCache`](http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/cache-bitmap.html) which works by allocating a specified amount of memory on the device's ram and removes old images to keep room, or clears it when the device needs more room for memory.